# Magento products not appearing in back end

Tags: magento, product

my products appear in the front end but my product information does not show up in the back end. Catalog > Manage Products > Select Product. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Please see screenshot here:
http://www.tollercranstonscarfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/products.png

Answer (score 1):

Install the Firebug extension in your browser, turn on the console and check for JavaScript errors. If you do not find it - check the logs of PHP and Magento.

Comment: Apparently I dont have a big enough reputation to vote your answer up but it was very useful I got some information:

ReferenceError: product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

...roduct_info_tabsJsTabs && product_info_tabsJsTabs.activeTab && $('store_switcher...

/index...90cc1b/ (line 785)
ReferenceError: product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

Product.AttributesBridge.setTabsObject(product_info_tabsJsTabs); Im not sure what this means :(

Comment: Oh, wonderful! Your help led me to the answer that solved the issue. Thank you so much! +1

Answer (score 0):

1. Check what all permissions you have as backend admin.